# ToolTipFor SeriesPoints not showing while using devexpress

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, devexpress, webchartcontrol

I have a webchartcontrol in my asp,net webforms, I have been trying to use the tooltip to show data when hovering over a point but the tooltip is never activated. I've tried different things I've found online. Below is the code I've been trying. Can someone show me what i've been doing wrong?

```
ActiveChart.CrosshairEnabled = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.False;
ActiveChart.ToolTipEnabled = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.True;
ActiveChart.Series[0].ToolTipEnabled = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.True;
ActiveChart.Series[0].ToolTipPointPattern = "{HINT} Test";
ActiveChart.Series[0].LabelsVisibility = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.True;
```

Comment: Have you tried to set ActiveChart.ToolTipOptions.ShowForSeries = true?

Comment: This code should work fine unless you use a Series view that does not support tooltips (all 3D Series views). If this is not the case, please share your chart Series definition.